# Change plot area background color

Tags: r, plot, xts

I would like to do a graph in R using our company colors. This means the background of all charts should be a light blue, the plotting region however should be white. I was searching for answers and found that drawing a rect does the job (almost). However the plotting region is now white and the graph not visible anymore. Is this even possible?

```
getSymbols('SPY', from='1998-01-01', to='2011-07-31', adjust=T)

GRAPH_BLUE<-rgb(43/255, 71/255,153/255)
GRAPH_ORANGE<-rgb(243/255, 112/255, 33/255)
GRAPH_BACKGROUND<-rgb(180/255, 226/255, 244/255)

par(bg=GRAPH_BACKGROUND)

colorPlottingBackground<-function(PlottingBackgroundColor = "white"){
  rect(par("usr")[1], par("usr")[3], par("usr")[2], par("usr")[4], col ="white")
}

plot.xts(SPY, col=GRAPH_BLUE)
colorPlottingBackground()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you plot your white rectangle after plotting your data, therefore overwriting them. Since `plot.xts` doesn't have an argument `add` that would allow you to call it after drawing the rectangle, the only solution I see would be to modify function `plot.xts`.

```
plot.xtsMODIFIED<-function (x, y = NULL, type = "l", auto.grid = TRUE, major.ticks = "auto", 
    minor.ticks = TRUE, major.format = TRUE, bar.col = "grey", 
    candle.col = "white", ann = TRUE, axes = TRUE, ...) 
{
    series.title <- deparse(substitute(x))
    ep <- axTicksByTime(x, major.ticks, format.labels = major.format)
    otype <- type
    if (is.OHLC(x) && type %in% c("candles", "bars")) {
        x <- x[, has.OHLC(x, TRUE)]
        xycoords <- list(x = .index(x), y = seq(min(x), max(x), 
            length.out = NROW(x)))
        type <- "n"
    }
    else {
        if (NCOL(x) > 1) 
            warning("only the univariate series will be plotted")
        if (is.null(y)) 
            xycoords <- xy.coords(.index(x), x[, 1])
    }
    ###The next three lines are the only modifications i made to the function####
    plot(xycoords$x, xycoords$y, type = "n", axes = FALSE, ann = FALSE) 
    rect(par("usr")[1], par("usr")[3], par("usr")[2], par("usr")[4], col ="white")
    if(type=="l"){lines(xycoords$x, xycoords$y, ...)}

    if (auto.grid) {
        abline(v = xycoords$x[ep], col = "grey", lty = 4)
        grid(NA, NULL)
    }
    if (is.OHLC(x) && otype == "candles") 
        plot.ohlc.candles(x, bar.col = bar.col, candle.col = candle.col, 
            ...)
    dots <- list(...)
    if (axes) {
        if (minor.ticks) 
            axis(1, at = xycoords$x, labels = FALSE, col = "#BBBBBB", 
                ...)
        axis(1, at = xycoords$x[ep], labels = names(ep), las = 1, 
            lwd = 1, mgp = c(3, 2, 0), ...)
        axis(2, ...)
    }
    box()
    if (!"main" %in% names(dots)) 
        title(main = series.title)
    do.call("title", list(...))
    assign(".plot.xts", recordPlot(), .GlobalEnv)
}
```

Then your script become:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('SPY', from='1998-01-01', to='2011-07-31', adjust=T)

GRAPH_BLUE<-rgb(43/255, 71/255,153/255)
GRAPH_BACKGROUND<-rgb(180/255, 226/255, 244/255)

par(bg=GRAPH_BACKGROUND)

plot.xtsMODIFIED(SPY, col=GRAPH_BLUE)
```

[image]

The error you're getting (`Error in axis(1, at = xycoords$x, labels = FALSE, col = "#BBBBBB", ...) : formal argument "col" matched by multiple actual arguments.`) was also thrown with your previous script. It has to do with the fact that `plot.xts` uses several time argument `...` and that argument `col` is both valid for `axis` and `plot`(or here in my modified version, `lines`). If you want to avoid it, i see two solutions: 
Either you want your axis to be of the same color as your line and therefore you have to change the line that says:

```
...
axis(1, at = xycoords$x, labels = FALSE, col = "#BBBBBB", 
            ...)
...
```

Into

```
...
axis(1, at = xycoords$x, labels = FALSE, ...)
...
```

Or you want the axis to have the color intended by the writer of the original `plot.xts` in which case you need to differenciate the color of the lines and that of the axis.

```
 plot.xtsMODIFIED<-function (x, y = NULL, type = "l", auto.grid = TRUE, major.ticks = "auto", 
                             minor.ticks = TRUE, major.format = TRUE, bar.col = "grey", 
                             candle.col = "white", ann = TRUE, axes = TRUE, 
                             lcol, ...) 
{
...
if(type=="l"){lines(xycoords$x, xycoords$y, lcol, ...)}
...
}
```

And then in your actual call:

```
plot.xtsMODIFIED(SPY, lcol=GRAPH_BLUE)
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot. Didn't think it's that complicated but thx for the code!

Comment: one more question though. if I do a plot with plot.xtsMODIFIED(SPY, col=GRAPH_BLUE) I get the error Error in axis(1, at = xycoords$x, labels = FALSE, col = "#BBBBBB", ...) : 
  formal argument "col" matched by multiple actual arguments. Why is this error thrown and how can I avoid that?

Answer (score 14):

I know you already accepted @plannapus's answer, but this is a much simpler solution

```
par(bg="lightblue")
plot(0, 0, type="n", ann=FALSE, axes=FALSE)
u <- par("usr") # The coordinates of the plot area
rect(u[1], u[3], u[2], u[4], col="white", border=NA)

par(new=TRUE)
plot(1:10, cumsum(rnorm(10)))
```

What you basically do is to overlay two plots using `par(new=TRUE)`: one with only a white rectangle; and another one with the contents you actually want to plot.

[image]

Comment: Arf, indeed, I never think of `par(new=TRUE)`.

Comment: It is a sneaky one :) I have found all sorts of usages for it when making plots that are out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 1):

`plot.xts` will accept the `panel.first` argument, which is another way to draw the rectangle before plotting the line.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('SPY', from='1998-01-01', to='2011-07-31', adjust=T)

GRAPH_BLUE<-rgb(43/255, 71/255,153/255)
GRAPH_BACKGROUND<-rgb(180/255, 226/255, 244/255)
par(bg=GRAPH_BACKGROUND)
white.rect=function() do.call(rect,as.list(c(par()$usr[c(1,3,2,4)],col="white")))
plot.xts(SPY,panel.first=white.rect())
```

This does not address the issue with `col=GRAPH_BLUE` pointed  out by @plannapus.